# React site build and deployment automation

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, github-pages

I have a ReactJs site which I make numerous changes to almost daily. My workflow once I'm done with coding is to commit to GitHub -> run npm run deploy which builds and deploys to gh-pages -> check the live version on the internet.

I wanted to automate this process so I tried GitHub actions. I changed my repos pages setting from deploy from branch to gh-actions. I accepted the default yml file after skimming through the gh-actions docs (seemed to accomplish what I wanted so I just went with it).

However, when I pushed some code on the repo then checked live, the site only showed the ReadMe file from the master branch. I kinda get how the automatic deployment works but somehow it deploys the ReadMe from the master branch rather than the gh-pages branch.

I don't really know how to fix it so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the yml file:

```
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Jekyll site to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy Jekyll with GitHub Pages dependencies preinstalled

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["master"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow one concurrent deployment
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v2
      - name: Build with Jekyll
        uses: actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
        with:
          source: ./
          destination: ./_site
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
```

I am trying to automatically build and deploy on changes to the master branch.

Comment: I usually use [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/KonradLinkowski/4b2b825d2540c4eecfc5dc1f9e42a87f)

Comment: Why do you deploy jekyll if you want to deploy a react app?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'm a self-taught beginner web dev so I'm learning this stuff on the go. I honestly don't even now what Jekyll is or what it does. Anyways should I change the output folder name from "dist" to something else. I feel like I should change it but I'm not sure where my output folder is. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Hey, @Konrad, nvm. Figured out it was supposed to be "build". It works. Thanks a mil.